# How to ensure XDebug is installed correctly?

Tags: php, iis, netbeans, xdebug

I've downloaded the PHP version of Netbeans from here:

https://netbeans.org/downloads/

And I've pasted the output from `phpinfo();` here:

https://xdebug.org/wizard.php

I followed their instructions:

- Download php_xdebug-2.5.0-5.6-vc11.dll
- Move the downloaded file to .\ext
- Edit `C:\php\php.ini` and added the following line to the bottom of my .ini:

> zend_extension = .\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.0-5.6-vc11.dll

- Restart the webserver (IIS 7.5)

I copied that line and pasted it at the very bottom of my `php.ini` file. Does it belong somewhere else? Under the `[PHP]` section?

When I run NetBeans, I've opened my project and went to `Properties` -> `Run Configuration` -> `Project URL` and updated that to the correct path (`http://localhost/myApplication/`).

When I press Ctrl-F5 (Debug Project) a browser window opens with the following in the address bar:

> http://localhost/myApplication/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug

So it looks like it's installed correctly, but if I set a breakpoint in my `index.php` file it doesn't trigger. I've tried setting other breakpoints throughout the software and those don't trigger, either.

I noticed in Netbeans, this progress bar just moves back and forth:

[image]

Should it be doing something?

**EDIT** Just doublechecked `phpinfo();` and now I see this:

> Zend Extension:   220131226
>
> Zend Extension Build: API220131226,TS,VC11
>
> This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
>   Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
>
> report_zend_debug: on, on

So it seems like it's installed... What am I doing wrong?

And here's a screenshot of `phpinfo();`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/noSx4.png

Comment: *"Restart the webserver (IIS 7.5)"* 1) How do you run PHP there? As CGI or FastCGI or what? On IIS 7+ it should be FastCGI .. so you must be using `nts` build of PHP and corresponding xdebug version. But right now I see that you are using `ts` versions (PHP and xdebug) .. so I'm not sure about all of this... Better look for "proper" PHP installation manual at https://php.iis.net/

Comment: 2) Do you see xdebug mentioned in `phpinfo()` output (captured via browser)? It should be mentioned in top table (bottom part, next to Zend Engine version/logo) as well as have separate xdebug section for settings

Comment: 3) What's your actual xdebug settings (in your php.ini)? By default xdebug will do nothing -- you have to configure it even start listening for debug requests/parameters.

Comment: **1)** FastCGI, I'm pretty sure. Under FastCGI settings in IIS I see php-cgi.exe listed. **2)** If I Ctrl-F for `xdebug`, I get zero results in my `phpinfo();` page. I will update my post with a screensot. **3)** The only thing I've done to `php.ini` is added the 1 line I quoted in my question.

Comment: **1)** Well .. I'm using it with IIS (with Windows 7/10 on my PC; Windows Server 2008/1012/2016 on VPS) .. and it's `nts` version of PHP. You will have to configure php.ini for this to work under IIS (few config values -- please refer to https://php.iis.net site  for manuals) **2)** xdebug regardless of OS and server requires at very least 1 or 2 lines of config in php.ini ([for example here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Xdebug+Installation+Guide))

Comment: **3)** Keep in mind that it's xdebug that connects to debug client (NetBeans in your case -- see info on how it works in general: https://xdebug.org/docs/remote) and not other way around -- so you may need to ensure that NetBeans can listen on xdebug port (e.g. allow it in firewall if needed).